# ASP.NET Core 5 How to Inject Dynamic Typed Object in _ViewImports.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

When I try to do this in my _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@inject dynamic ResourceManager;
```

I can use it in my views like the following:

```
Some text @ResourceManager.MyRuntimeBoundProperty some more text
```

However, when I try to run this solution, I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.Object' has been registered. Source: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs:line 59
```

I want to avoid specifying an actual type for ResourceManager because its properties are set at run time and can vary quite a bit.

Is there a way to specify a dynamic object in _ViewImports.cshtml, or otherwise access a dynamically populated ResourceManager across all of my views?

Comment: You cannot inject something with a dynamic type because for dependency injection, the actual type is what determines what kind of dependency will be injected. So you will need some static type there; otherwise, how should the system know what to inject here? It could inject a string to satisfy this requirement which obviously wouldn’t work for you. – So what are you actually trying to inject here?

Comment: The original code (ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2) had a view base class that provided a dynamic ResourceManager. I need to follow this by having a dynamic ResourceManager in the ASP.NET Core 5 migration.

I have compromised by providing a providing a concrete type for ResourceManager and then casting it to dynamic whenever it's used, and then accessing the various property names from the dynamic cast. I don't know if this will actually work yet, as I don't have that piece of code running. I doubt it will, but can't confirm just yet.

Thanks for your advice. That confirms my thinking, too.

Comment: Classic ASP.NET didn’t use dependency injection though. If you want to pass a dynamic object, I would suggest you to pass this as [`ViewData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag) instead. You could set that in your controller, or even prepare it in your `_ViewStart.cshtml` so that it will be available everywhere. Other than that, you could also inject a properly-typed object that has a dynamic property itself which you can then use to access this ressource manager.

Comment: Thank you for those ideas, poke. I will discuss it with out team!

Comment: Just following up: I used Poke's idea of creating a properly typed object that has a dynamic property, and that's what I'm using to access the resource. Works great! Poke, if you want to post that as your answer, I'll mark it as the answer and you can get your credit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic with dependency injection because DI works by using *types* as the primary mechanism to determine what instances it should inject into your dependent component. So you will *need* to use some static type if you want to use dependency injection here.

One way to approach this would be to introduce a statically typed wrapper object which then provides access to your dynamic object. E.g. something like this:

```cs
public class ResourceManagerWrapper
{
    public dynamic Resources { get; set; }
}
```

If you register that as a scoped or singleton dependency, you can inject it earlier in your pipeline, set the `Resources` object to your dynamic resource manager and then access it in your view:

```html
@inject ResourceManagerWrapper resourceManager

Some text @resourceManager.Resources.MyRuntimeBoundProperty some more text
```

An alternative solution would be to not use dependency injection here but instead pass this dynamic resource manager directly into your view. You could do this through the view model, or using the [`ViewData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag) mechanism that is available with Razor views. That way, you could set some `ViewData["ResourceManager"]` and then load that value in your view:

```
@{
    dynamic resourceManager = ViewData["ResourceManager"];
}
```

You can also do this within the `_ViewStart.chtml`, so that it runs by default in all your views.

Comment: A beautiful and useful answer! Thank you very much!